# Polymer element height when it contains content tag

Tags: polymer

I have an issue, when i try to load content into my element, it is always has height = 0, i need element to be sized by content size, is there any suggestions?
There is my template

```
<template>
    <paper-dialog id="dialog" modal>
        <h2>{{_computeTitle()}}</h2>
        <paper-dialog-scrollable id="main">
            <content id="form" select=".content"></content>
        </paper-dialog-scrollable>
        <div class="buttons">
            <content select=".buttons"></content>
        </div>
    </paper-dialog>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using a scrollable dialog inside of a dialog? You should use a dialog and give the children the position: relative property.